# Showing errors while copying all values of a column from a google sheet and add them as editors in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy all values (emails) of column 6 from a Google sheet to an array and then add those emails to the spreadsheet as editors.

But it shows:

> Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.addEditor.

```
function refreshSheet() { 

      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

      //StudentList is a student information sheet where in Column F all the emails of students kept.  
      var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('StudentList');

      //Need to bring all students emails from Column of StudentList sheet to students array. 
      var data = sheet1.getLastRow();
      var students = [];
      var students = sheet1.getRange(2, 6, data).getValues();  

      var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
      for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){
        ss.addEditor(students[i]); 
      }  

      //Now start a timer and after 5/10/15 minutes all students should be removed automatically from Editor to Viewer Mode.    
      Utilities.sleep(300000);
      Utilities.sleep(300000);
      Utilities.sleep(300000);
      for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
          ss.removeEditor(students[i]);
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

When using `.getValues()` function on multi-row range you will get a multi-dimensional array which the first index will represent the row index and the second one will represent the column:

```js
let values = range.getValues(); //values[row][columns]
```

So you should actually access to the second index when looking for the value in the wanted range.

Here is a modification suggestion to your script in order for it to work:

```js
 for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++){ // you are looping through rows and selecting the 1st and only column index
     if (students[i][0] !== '') ss.addEditor(students[i][0].toString()); 
 }
```

### Reference

[Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)